# Multidex is not supporting in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Note: C:\temp\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\device_info-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\deviceinfo\DeviceInfoPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
ERROR:D8: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad byte
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.1.66.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:68)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.b(SourceFile:3)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:136)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad byte
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.W0.a(SourceFile:42)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.W0.N(SourceFile:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.W0.toString(SourceFile:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.X0.y0(SourceFile:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.r.a(SourceFile:259)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(SourceFile:2)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad format
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:98)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(D8.java:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:11)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:24)
        at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.b(SourceFile:3)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:136)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad format
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.B.a(SourceFile:50)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:79)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad format
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:600)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad format
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.W0.toString(SourceFile:3)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.X0.y0(SourceFile:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.r.a(SourceFile:259)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(SourceFile:2)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
    Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad byte]


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 54s
[!] App requires Multidex support
    Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

    Flutter tool can add multidex support. The following file will be added by flutter:

        android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/app/FlutterMultiDexApplication.java
```

Getting above error in Flutter sdk 3.3.9

App requires Multidex support
Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

The current Dart SDK version is 2.16.0.

Because wvc_exchange requires SDK version >=2.18.5 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in wvc-exchange-app...
pub get failed (1; Because wvc_exchange requires SDK version >=2.18.5 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdk = 15 
        targetSdk = 33
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working

Comment: have you tried flutter clean after that?

Comment: Yes. I did clean and pub get. also restart my system

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it more clear, check if it's the same for you. You can build the assembly with --multidex as flutter build apk --multidex

Comment: Ok. When run above command it shows me error

Comment: It shows me dart sdk version error

Comment: update pubspec 
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.5 <3.0.0"

Comment: it is already this

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

**in command line run**

```
flutter run --debug
```

if multidex support has not been properly enabled, error logs will show up as below

[image: multidex-error]

**when prompted to enable multidex, type y as highlighted in the image above**

your app will be rebuilt with multidex enabled.

This will properly enable multidex support on your flutter app, hope it helps!